# Library/framework to help Sharepoint development?

Tags: 2010

I am looking for a Sharepoint library or framework to help speed my development on an upcoming project. Just like jQuery made writing Javascript so much easier, is there an equivalent for Sharepoint? Something to help reduce bugs and make life easier when developing?

Ideally, it would be for 2010...

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no such library or framework for SharePoint akin to jquery but there are tools which definitely makes our SharePoint development experience much better.

Please check this [link](http://www.silver-it.com/node/101). These tools really help us do our job better.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't SPServices be a good alternative?

See spservices.codeplex.com

Comment: Please motivate and add some explanation on why to use the SPServices